# How to get the Topleft, TopRight coordinates (corners) of a CIImage in iOS (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ciimage

I try to get the value of the topleft of a CIImage, but impossible to see where it is...

When I print the CIImage, I can see that informations :

(I print this value in the self.cameraView.lastCorrectedUIImage in the IRLScannerViewController).

```
 <CIImage: 0x170009440 extent [0 0 768 502]>
      crop [0 0 767.499 501.021] extent=[0 0 767.499 501.021]
        warpkernel _perspectiveCorrection(A1=[0.320876 -0.610103 0.683767],A2=[1.48175 0.21446 0.259627],A3=[0.183574 -0.0464235 1],rect=[0 0 767.499 501.021]) extent=[-112.259 -138.573 1060.3 864.268]
          color_matrix r=(0.24225 0.815556 0.082194 0) g=(0.24225 0.815556 0.082194 0) b=(0.24225 0.815556 0.082194 0) a=(0 0 0 1) bias=(-0.07 -0.07 -0.07 0) extent=[0 0 750 1000]
            affine [1 0 0 -1 0 1000] extent=[0 0 750 1000]
              colormatch "QuickTime 'nclc' Video (1,1,6)"-to-workingspace extent=[0 0 750 1000]
                IOSurface 0x170008d70 BGRA8 extent=[0 0 750 1000]
```

I would like, at least, to access to the perspectiveCorrection...

Comment: Which value in the print output are you looking for?

Comment: I check the value in the self.cameraView.lastCorrectedUIImage by using IRLScannerViewController

Comment: Which value exactly do you want to get? Which one do you think is the *topleft* of the image? Probably not (0, 0).

Comment: What I believe is that two values A1=[0.320876 -0.610103 0.683767] and A2=[1.48175 0.21446 0.259627] allows me to know if the image is with the left corner upstairs or downstairs. I did lot of tests